# bash script: {dir1,dir2,dir3} expansion not working as expected from variable, for picking a random file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a problem, with this simple script (pick a random file):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
srcDir="/home/user/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3}"
randomFile=$(find "$srcDir" -type f -iname "*.jpg" | shuf -n 1)
printf '[%s]\n' $randomFile
set +x
```

The problem is that while I can type this at the command line (and works perfectly fine):

```
find /home/user/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3} -type f -iname "*.jpg"
```

Then the bash debugging set-commands (set -x and +x) tells me, that for some reason bash both encloses the directory string with single quotation marks and it also replaces the double quotation marks with single quotation marks?

```
./script.sh
+ srcDir='/home/user/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3}'
++ find '/home/user/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3}' -type f -iname '"*.jpg"'
find: ‘/home/user/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3}’: No such file or directory
+ randomFile=
+ printf '[%s]\n'
[]
+ set +x
```

I understand, this is what bash sees, when the script runs:

```
find '/home/user/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3}' -type -iname '*.jpg'
```

And this causes the "No such file or directory"-message, very very annoying... I do not understand, why it inserts these single quotation marks, I want double quotation marks used instead, just like on the command line... Could anyone please explain, I would be happy for that, thanks!

Comment: It's not `"*.jpg"` that doesn't happen, it's `{dir1,dir2,dir3}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. On second thought: Isn't it both? I also don't think '*.jpg' expands correctly (if there wasn't a single quotation mark around '*.jpg', which was shown from inside the "set -x" and "set +x"-section, I would agree... But I honestly also do not know why bash encloses the directory and the file inside single quotation mark...

Comment: `*.jpg`, in `find . -iname '*.jpg'`, is parsed by `find`, not by bash; it's *expected* that it not be expanded by the shell -- if it were, `find` would never see it. Thus, having a single layer of syntactic quotes (and no literal quotes) is entirely correct and desired in that case. ("Literal" quotes are quotes that are *part of the data*, and thus passed to `find`; "syntactic" quotes are quotes that are *part of the shell syntax*, and thus consumed by bash itself).

Comment: @Charles Duffy Ok, thank you. I'm not that used to the terminology about syntactic / literal quotes. But it's very helpful of you elaborate, thank you very much (eventually I'll hopefully learn it)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Brace expansion doesn't occur within a variable assignment, as explained here:

[Why do tilde prefixes expand prior to assignment, but braces don't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485970/why-do-tilde-prefixes-expand-prior-to-assignment-but-braces-dont)

In other contexts, the quotes would have prevented brace expansion as well.

Even if you do manage to get `srcDir` to expand to a list of directories, quoting it again in the `find` command will cause it to be treated as a single argument instead of 3 separate paths.

Probably the right way to do this in bash is to use an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
srcDir=("/home/user/Desktop/wallPapers/"{dir1,dir2,dir3})
randomFile=$(find "${srcDir[@]}" -type f -iname "*.jpg" | shuf -n 1)
printf '[%s]\n' "$randomFile"
set +x
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution I was looking for, thank you very much. You keep using the variables, which I wanted to learn how to use. Also, I didn't realise/knew I had to use an array, now I know in the future. In the top of my script I then define "srcDir" - and then the script does whatever it's supposed to do later on, with the result in the "randomFile"-variable. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

As others have already pointed out, the quotes are preventing the brace expansion. You could simplify your script to just:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
printf '[%s]\n' "$(find /home/terdon/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3} -type f -iname "*.jpg" | shuf -n 1)"
```

Or, if your file names can contain newline characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
printf '[%s]\n' "$(find /home/terdon/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3} -type f -iname "*.jpg" -print0| shuf -zn 1)"
```

If you want something that can run on arbitrary directories and file types, try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

targetFilePattern="$1"
shift
declare -a targetDirs=("$@")
echo "find ${targetDirs[@]} -type f -iname '$targetFilePattern' | shuf -n 1"
randomFile=$(find "${targetDirs[@]}" -type f -iname "$targetFilePattern" | shuf -n 1)
echo "$randomFile"
```

You can then run it as:

```
printRandomFile '*jpg' /home/terdon/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3}
```

Or even

```
printRandomFile '*jpg' /home/terdon/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3,'a dir with a space'}
```

Comment: Thanks - also this looks a bit "hardcoded" - I wanted to have the resulting random file-name in a new variable, so I could keep do some manipulation later on in the script. The prinf was only for myself, to see the value. Sorry, you, couldn't know that, because I didn't tell it before... I'm however upvoting for the good explanation, as my way of saying thanks.

Comment: @OkayDokey if you want it in a variable, just use `randomFile="$(find /home/terdon/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3} -type f -iname "*.jpg" -print0| shuf -zn 1)"`

Comment: Yes, ok, I know. But the path is kind of "hard-coded" which is ok for a small script. But you're right. The solutions you presented are all good, thanks.

Comment: @OkayDokey see update for how to make it truly not hardcoded.

Comment: Very, very nice, thank you very much, this is also (more of) what I was looking for...

Answer (score 3):

Brace expansion isnt performed inside double quotes. There is a duplicate question regarding this somewhere. Also, use -printf flag for find, doing command substitution is unnecessary, so you can do this

```
find /home/user/Desktop/wallPapers/{dir1,dir2,dir3} -type f -iname "*.jpg" -printf '[%f]\n' | shuf -n1
```

Comment: This breaks in the unlikely case where the file names contain newlines.

Comment: Fair point, `-print0` is better for those cases

Comment: Thank you very much, but for a script that could eventually become bigger I prefer executing some kind of expression, based on variables, defined in the top of the script. This looks a bit more like something on the command line - but I upvoted, due to the explanation. The purpose of my script was also not to just print something out on the screen (the printf-line) - but to do some further manipulation. I know you couldn't see that from my original post, so sorry about that... And thanks.

Comment: @OkayDokey you seem to be misunderstanding. This (and all other answers so far) are no more "hardcoded" than your approach. But perhaps we can give you better solutions if you edit your question and explain in more detail.

Comment: @OkayDokey If you do need to use dir1,dir2,dir3 later in a script, use set command or array to save the directory names. I would explain further but currently have no time. And yes, it was not obvious that you want to reuse those further.

Comment: @terdon: Well, ok, the primary input here is the directory path of source files. Alternatively, the "*.jpg" could also be a kind of user-defined input. What I meant is that e.g. the "srcDir" should be in the top of the script and I only learned now that the solution was an array. What I meant by "hardcoded" is that the variable "srcDir" was not used...

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy : I didn't know about the set command/array. It's ok if you don't follow up (but I'll read the answer and learn from it, if you write later). The main problem has already been solved and I marked it as accepted/solved + I upvoted all your answers, because I realized that you all provedid helpful answers and you couldn't exactly know what I was looking for, because I forgot or wasn't 100% accurate, when I wrote the question (I wanted to have the source directory from a variable - instead of typing it there directly)...

Comment: @OkayDokey instead of using variables at the top of the script (also known as "hardcoding" :P) you might want to look into using the `$@` array and pass the variables as arguments to the script. That's the most versatile way of doing this and the only way that doesn't involve hardcoding the values. Feel free to ping me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) if you want help with that, or just post a new question.

Comment: @terdon I appreciate your very nice updated post with really good examples and learningful comments (including $@). It's enough for me now, but thanks a lot for the offer, my conclusion at this point is that I highly appreciate the examples and learningful comments...